# Laravel blade template engine :cannot see html contents in page

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to integrate blade template engine in CodeIgniter framework using library method.

Here are the steps I followed

1.Download the blade template engine via composer and copy to `application/libraries` folder.

2.Created a class named `Bladetemplate` in libraries folder

**Bladetemplate.php**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/blade/vendor/autoload.php';

use Philo\Blade\Blade;

    class Bladetemplate  {

        public function loadTemplate(){
            $views = APPPATH. '\views';
            $cache = APPPATH. '\cache';

           $blade = new Blade($views, $cache);
           return $blade;


        }
    }
```

3.In my controller file, I've loaded the library and call the function `loadTemplate` for blade template view

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('Bladetemplate');
       //template object
        $obj=   $this->bladetemplate->loadTemplate();
        $obj->view()->make('test',array('data'=>'test'))->render(); 
    }
```

In my `applications/views` folder file named `test.blade.php` is present

There is no error is shown, but  nothing displayed on the page ( some HTML contents are present).

Comment: Don't you need to `echo` the render ? Also, could  you dump out the $views path. Other than that I don't see any problem.

Answer (score -2):

Change your view file name to add **.blade**. Like if your view file **test.php** than make it **test.blade.php**

Instead of  **$obj->view()->make('test',array('data'=>'test'))->render();**

you need to use **$obj->view()->make('test.blade',array('data'=>'test'))->render();**

Whenever you are using blade template, you have to render your view as blade type. So, **test.blade**

I hope, It will work.

If not, let me know.

Comment: Nop it returns view not found exception

Comment: Ok.

Have you to pass any data into view ? may be that's the reason, you getting nothing.

Comment: I am tried with and without data but I will get empty page in both cases